# How to put debugging statements in a Jquery Code

Tags: jquery

Friends
Im trying to debug the Jquery code using simple Alert('Flow1'); , console.log('Test1'); and using debugger; statement inside my JQuery Code which is

**However Nothing is working out as Alert('Flow1'); , console.log('Test1'); do not throw debugging Alerts when the following JQuery code gets executed**

```
function handleChannelTabs() {
        debugger;
            Alert('Test1');
        console.log('Test1');
        var checkedBoxes = [];
        var checkedChannelsLength = $("[data-channel-checkboxes]").find(
        "input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        $("[data-channel-checkboxes]").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked")
                .each(function() {
                    checkedBoxes.push($(this).val())
                    var self = $(this)
                    var contentDiv = $('[data-content-for=' + self.val() + ']')
                    if (self.is(':checked')) {
                        if (checkedChannelsLength > 1) {
                            contentDiv.children().appendTo(
                                    $('[data-tab-content-for=' + self.val()
                                            + ']'))
                        } else {
                            $('[data-tab-content-for=' + self.val() + ']')
                                    .children().appendTo(contentDiv)
                        }
                    }
                })
        var isFirstTab = true;
        $("[data-channel-content]").toggleClass('hidden', checkedBoxes.length < 2)
        $("[data-channel-content]").find('ul').find('li').each(
                function(index) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log('Test6');
                    var currentLi = $(this);
                    if (jQuery.inArray($(currentLi).find('a').html(),
                            checkedBoxes) >= 0) {
                        $(currentLi).removeClass('hidden')
                        if (isFirstTab) {
                            isFirstTab = false;
                            $(currentLi).addClass("active").css('margin-left', '20px').find('a').addClass("act-a");
                            $($('[data-tab-content-for]')[index]).removeClass('hidden')
                        } else {
                            $(currentLi).removeClass("active").css('margin-left', '0px').find('a').removeClass("act-a");
                            $($('[data-tab-content-for]')[index]).addClass('hidden')
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(currentLi).addClass('hidden')
                    }
                })
}
```

Comment: which browser are you using? have you turned on dev tools in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
Alert('Test1');
```

is <s>a syntax error</s> not defined, it should be:

```
alert('Test1');
```

in lowercase

Comment: To be fair, that's valid syntax, but the name `Alert` is not bound to anything.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - that's true, it's not a syntax error, it's simply not defined.

Answer (score 1):

use `alert` instead of `Alert`. `console.log` will log the value in browser console. To view browser console press `F12` or open  `developer tool`

Answer (score 0):

1) download the firebug on your browser 
2) then press the F12
3) click on script tag
4) select your jquery file 
5) where want you debugger go to that line and mouse click on before that line number